# Ruby const_get that searches lexical scope

Tags: ruby

Given a string "XYZZY" in ruby I would like a version of const_get that will find that constant within the lexical scoping chain.

For example in the following `Whack` get looked up just fine, but when I do a const_get on the string 'Whack' it just does the const lookup in the current scope, i.e. it does not search... is there a version of const_get that will search?

```
module Foo
  class Whack
  end
  module Bar
    class Baz
      def self.test(s)
        const_get s.to_s
      end
      def self.test1
        test(Whack)
      end
    end
  end
end

puts Foo::Bar::Baz.test1
puts Foo::Bar::Baz.test("Whack")
```

outputs

```
>Foo::Whack
>Whack: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar::Baz::Whack
```

In the meantime I am using this code:

```
  def const_get_with_lookup(name)
    scopes = self.class.name.split('::').inject([Module]) do |nesting, next_const|
      nesting + [nesting.last.const_get(next_const)]
    end.reverse
    scopes.each do |scope|
      return scope.const_get(name) if scope.const_defined?(name)
    end
  end
```

which works, but it seems like I am working way to hard...

Comment: The reason that `test1` works is that when you call `to_s` on your class, you're not getting back the string `"Whack"`, you're getting back the string `"Foo::Whack"`. If you pass `"Foo::Whack"` to `test`, that'll work too.